# Is this equation right?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

This is one step in a exercise, $f(x)$ is a odd function

> $$ \int_0^xf(u)\mathrm{d}u-xf(x) = \int_0^x\left[f(u)-f(x)\right]\mathrm{d}x $$

I don't understand why they are equal.

In my view, the RHS is equal to

> $$ \int_0^xf(u)\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^xf(x)\mathrm{d}x = f(u)x- \int_0^xf(x)\mathrm{d}x $$

It is obvious they are not equal.

Is  $ xf(x) = \int_0^xf(x)\mathrm{d}x $ right ?

Comment: It ought to be $du$ instead of $dx$ on the right hand side.

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I understand, the book is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $x\,f(x) = \int_0^xf(x)\,dx$ is not completely accurate, because you use the same symbol as the integration variable and the limit of integration.
It would be more accurate to write $x\,f(x) = \int_0^xf(x)\,dt$, in which case the integrand $f(x)$ will not appear to depend on the variable of integration $t$, so that
$$
\int_0^xf(x)\,du = f(x) \int_0^x1\,du = f(x)\, \Big(u\;\big|_{0}^{x}\Big) =
f(x)\, \big( x - 0\big) = x\,f(x) .
$$

Now, you original problem

> $$\int_0^xf(u)\mathrm{d}u-xf(x) = \int_0^x\left[f(u)-f(x)\right]\mathrm{d}x$$

seem to have mistake.

I believe it should be $d\,u$, not $d\,x$ in the right hand side of the equation. In that case
$$
\int_0^xf(u)\,du-xf(x) =  \int_0^xf(u)\,du - \int_0^xf(x)\,du =  \int_0^x\big[\,f(u)-f(x)\big]\,dx.
$$
*Q.E.D.*